# Edit HTML list entry with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists, edit

Note: i searched a half hour. I need a special solution for this:

I have the folowing code already (node some Variables have german Names i hope that's ok)

```
function generateList () {


document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML =""

var listEasy = vorNameListe[i] + " " + nachNameListe[i] + " " + alterListe[i]

for (var i=0; i < vorNameListe.length; i++) {

document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML += "<li>" + listEasy + "</li>"
};
```

Now i need a javascript (pls no jquery) solution so the user can change every List entry by himself. How do i do that?

further explanation: The code i have is one to bring a "li" in a existing "ul" with every loop. 
But then i want to give every "li entry" the ability to be changed by the user.

Comment: You can't use `i` outside the loop.

Comment: Whats your point? The loop works!

Comment: PS I dont want to use [i] outside the loop...

Comment: In your example you clearly do.

Comment: In my example i set a var called listEasy. Then I set the var list Easy in the for loop. so in the End its like this:

for (var i=0; i < vorNameListe.length; i++) {

document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML += "<li>" + vorNameListe[i] + " " + nachNameListe[i] + " " + alterListe[i]
+ "</li>"};

i hope now you get it. its not that i dont now about scopes, i just used a var to make it clearer.

If u dont undertsand it, forget about it, i need something to Edit my <li> entrys.

Comment: Maybe I should just correct my comment. You should't do such things. It just makes your code less maintainable. I know that it works that way, but in a more complex project this could cause you some trouble.

Comment: OKay in my next projekt i will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i refined my edit function with jquery fdurther and further i will edit this entry for every step:

[I have a Special Idea about an Edit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562007/i-have-a-special-idea-about-an-edit-function)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695711/edit-and-delete-selected-list-entrys

Comment: also this is realy ppossible with Javascript only. I add this when someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change text of every li of #liste ul?

```
function generateList() {
    var liItems = document.querySelectorAll('#liste > li');
    for (i = 0; i === liItems, i++) {
        liItems[i].innerHTML = 'content';
    }
}
```

Comment: further explanation: The code i have is one to bring a "li" in a existing "ul" with every loop. 
But then i want to give every "li entry" the ability to be changed by the user.

Comment: If you want such an interaction I really would advice you to take a look ar jQuery or AngularJS even though you dont want to. It is worth it.

Comment: I will do it when the time comes. But the thing is first i need to fully understand what javascript can do. I got said that its possible to do, but i stil dont know how.

Comment: Question: how would it look in jQuery or Angular JS?