# Can I have only one Index from a click event selected Item?

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, target, targeting

I have Problems with editing and deleting selected entries. i think it lies that i get only one index.

How i select things:

```
$("#liste").click(function selectList (event) {
        var target = $( event.target );
        if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
            target.toggleClass('selected');
        }
    });
```

The Problem is here:

```
$('.selected').attr("index");
```

I only get the first Index from the selected Item, but i want to have all the indexes for every selected item. For Questionslook at this [I have a Special Idea about an Edit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562007/i-have-a-special-idea-about-an-edit-function) or feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr()` will, as you say, return the attribute from the first element in the matched set.  If you want all of the `index` attributes from the selected objects, use `map()`:

```
var indices = $('.selected').map( 
  function() {
    return $(this).attr('index');
  }
);
```

```js
var indices = $('.selected').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('index');
});

console.log(indices);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected" index="one"></div>
<div class="selected" index="two"></div>
<div index="three"></div>
<div class="selected" index="four"></div>
<div index="five"></div>
```

Comment: So map creates an Object with all the index?

Comment: No, `map()` returns the result of some function, performed on each element in the array; the result is *also* an array. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info.